# Accumulating backlog on std::cin causes it to lose data

Tags: c++, linux, unix, pipe

I have an external binary that produces an infinite stream of binary data (~10 MiB/s) to stdout, and I am trying to write a C++ program to consume it. My consumer program has a somewhat unusual pattern: it first reads a small amount of data from the stream (~32KiB), processes that for about one minute, and then starts consuming data again at a much faster rate (> 50 MiB/s).

I am invoking the program as follows: `$ my_producer | my_consumer`.

Because the consumer is initially much slower than the consumer, I expect the pipe to build a backlog of about `60s * 10 MiB/s = 600 MiB`. However, after the initial delay of one minute, my consumer starts consuming data at only ~10MiB/s, implying that the data produced during that one-minute interval was lost; why?

The relevant code for the consumer is something like this:

```
std::vector<char> StreamSource::Read(std::size_t size) {
  auto data = std::vector<char>(size);
  stream_.read(data.data(), size);
  data.resize(stream_.gcount());
  assert(stream_.good() || stream_.eof());
  return data;
}

std::istream& stream_;  // Initialized to std::cin
```

Interestingly, writing to file and then piping that file to the consumer works as expected!

```
$ my_producer > ~/Desktop/data
$ cat ~/Desktop/data | my_consumer
```

I run a bunch of tests to make sure my producer is not likely to blame; the following fails because the producer detects a "short write":

```
$ my_producer | throttle -M1 > ~/Desktop/data
```

I'm looking for advice on how to explain the missing data. In case it's relevant, I am running on MacOS.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure no OS allows the pipe to build up to 600mb, the write end will block when the pipe is full. If you want to allow that much data to build up you need to have a thread in your application which is reading from `cin` continuously and buffering the data, your application can then read from that buffer rather than `cin`.

According to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer the pipe is generally maximum of 64K.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Alan! I agree -- a buffer that size is problematic, and reading the data in to my consumer will probably fix it. I'd still want to understand what is happening, and how to detect this. It seems unlikely that the write is blocking, since the producer is not failing (see my example with `throttle`). Who's dropping these bytes?

Comment: Without a [mre] its difficult to tell. It's entirely possible that the producer has a separate thread producing data to writing data and if the data can't be written fast enough it discards it